# Using GAMLSS predictions within a wrapper function

Tags: r, prediction, environment, gamlss, r-environment

I'm trying to write functions that wrap basic gamlss modeling (because I'm preparing a higher-level, application-specific package). But I've run into issues wrapping predict.

The example from the `predict.gamlss` [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamlss/index.html) works well:

```
suppressMessages(library(gamlss))
data(aids)
  
a<-gamlss(y~poly(x,3)+qrt, family=PO, data=aids) 
#> GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 416.8014 
#> GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 416.8014
newaids<-data.frame(x=c(45,46,47), qrt=c(2,3,4))
predict(a, newdata = newaids)
#> Warning in predict.gamlss(a, newdata = newaids): There is a discrepancy  between the original and the re-fit 
#>  used to achieve 'safe' predictions 
#> 
#> [1] 6.021313 6.232357 6.155965
```

But as soon as I wrap it, the code fails:

```
gamlss_fit <- function(input) {
  gamlss(y~poly(x,3)+qrt, family=PO, data=input) 
}

gamlss_predict <- function(fit, input) {
  predict(fit, newdata = input)
}

fit <- gamlss_fit(aids)
#> GAMLSS-RS iteration 1: Global Deviance = 416.8014 
#> GAMLSS-RS iteration 2: Global Deviance = 416.8014
gamlss_predict(fit, newaids)
#> Error in eval(Call$data): object 'input' not found
```

I vaguely suspect there's an issue managing the assumed `environment`. I've tried looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/cran/gamlss/blob/master/R/predict.gamlss_23_12_21.R) of `predict.gamlss`, but I haven't been able to follow it. The problem seems related to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742461/error-when-predicting-new-fitted-values-from-r-gamlss-object), but the original `newdata` call works in my case. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the same issue by add the input dataset to the global environment within the function. Try:

```
gamlss_predict <- function(fit, input) {
  input <<- input
  predict(fit, newdata = input)
  rm(input)
}
```